# Is it possible to copy an append changes column's values from an old list to a new list?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem

I have an older list with a multi line plain text +append changes column. I want to migrate the items on the list to a new list.

Is it possible to migrate the column's entries to the new list while maintaining the date and user information?

Answer (score -1):

Not without either a migration tool or some custom code somebody would have to write.

Comment: What kind of code?

Comment: PowerShell or .NET

Comment: I can work with both of those but I'm not familiar with copying append change columns around, how would that work? Maybe you could expand your answer a bit.

Comment: You need to parse out the version history to get append-only comments.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Is this answer wrong?